# How to recreate SQLite Database at runtime when using Room in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I want to nuke the database and recreate it at runtime. 
I used this in base activity to nuke the database and it successfully did it 
`deleteDatabase(AppDatabase.getDATABASE_NAME());`

I then used the following code to clear all back stack and open the launch activity

```
Intent intent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().
getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now when I try to insert into database via Room it throws the following error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:80)
at android.arch.persistence.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insertAndReturnId(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:114)
at xx.yy.data.local.db.user.UserDao_Impl.insertUser(UserDao_Impl.java:124)
at xx.yy.data.local.db.DbHelper.saveUserDetails(DbHelper.kt:51)
at xx.yy.data.DataManager.saveUserDetailsToLocal(DataManager.kt:101)
at xx.yy.data.DataManager$signUp$1.call(DataManager.kt:146)
at xx.yy.data.DataManager$signUp$1.call(DataManager.kt:29)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:511)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:466)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:244)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:148)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.deliverResponse(CallArbiter.java:118)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.emitResponse(CallArbiter.java:100)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:46)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:24)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:100)
at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:230)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: I will be surprised if Room supports deleting the database entirely while your process is running.

Comment: @CommonsWare, then what do you suggest to solve the problem?

Comment: Delete the contents of the tables. Or, find some way to avoid the need to nuke the database. Eventually, Room will need some more smarts for this sort of thing, to support database restoration from a backup and stuff, but I don't think that it's there right now. In particular, since I am not aware of a `deleteDatabase()` method in the Room API, I assume that you are doing this outside of Room, and Room *definitely* will not be happy when you change things behind its back.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Yes you are correct, I am not deleting the database using room, but via android context method. Will dig into this to get the task done. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As @commonsware suggested you in comments section, You can delete all the records from the table using Room as below:

```
@Query("delete * from "+ TABLE_NAME)
void deleteAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may either delete all tables (and set the seq back to 0 after) or you can create a memory database which holds the database in your memory.

```
@Query("DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_NAME)
void deleteAll();

@Query("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + TABLE_NAME + "'");
void resetSeq();
```

and creating the memory database instead:

```
Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(application, YourDBClass.class).build()
```