# Clearing the Auto-Increment value after calling clearAllTables()

Tags: android, android-room

Android Room version 1.1.0 now provides the method [`clearAllTables()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase#clearalltables).

Altough this method is very convenient, it does not clear the auto-increment value generated by the by [`autoGenerate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/PrimaryKey#autoGenerate()), as stated in the official documentation.

I would also like to clear the primary keys of all the tables in my database, without having to call individual queries for each table.

Comment: see https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html, section `"The AUTOINCREMENT Keyword"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I completely recreate my database in Android Room?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810358/how-do-i-completely-recreate-my-database-in-android-room)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1601854/115145), I would assume that this SQL statement would work:

```
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='table1' OR name='table2';
```

...chaining on as many `OR` clauses as needed.

However, `sqlite_sequence` is not a Room-managed table, so you may need to execute this SQL using a `SupportSQLiteDatabase`. You get one of those by calling `getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase()` on your `RoomDatabase`.

However, I would not bother with this. IMHO, you should not be relying on any particular behavior of `AUTOINCREMENT` (e.g., always starting from some specific value). In that case, it's unclear what value there is in hacking SQLite to reset these values.

Comment: It is not that I am relying on the Primary Key to start from some specific value, it is just that I am worried about any future problems should the primary key overflow. Do I have to worry about it overflowing?

Comment: @Tjaart: Um, well, things start to get interesting after the first 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 rows. The Sun might go nova before you use that many. See [the docs that pskink pointed to](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) for more details about the number allocation.