# How To recreate Room Database From Assets?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have preloaded database in Asset folder and it contain all data , when i Edit my database in Asset and increase version number and using **fallbackToDestructiveMigration()** app is work but it lose all data i want to know how to recreate database with room from assets using **fallbackToDestructiveMigration()** and then coping all tables from assets to new database
i tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810358/how-do-i-completely-recreate-my-database-in-android-room) but didn't work and i tired also Migrating but my database have a lot of tables and rows so i can't do that

i'm using Hilt and provides room like this :

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideMyDataBase(mApplication: Application): MyDataBase {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(mApplication, MyDataBase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
        .createFromAsset(DATABASE_NAME)
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .build()
}
```

Comment: Make sure the prepopulated database has the same version number and the same table structure as the current database. You can DB Browser to updated the DB, use the Database inspector provided by Android Studio to compare both versions. I was facing the similar and resolved it by following above steps.

Comment: @AlphaOne My preloaded has not version table and all tables are same structure beacuse when i clear data  it works fine but when update my app the new version not work the database empty so i'm trying to find a way when i increase version number the database also copy data from assets to and delete previous tables

Answer (score 0):

You can prepopulate it with your initial values when its created

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
    DataDatabase::class.java, "Sample.db")
    // prepopulate the database after onCreate was called
    .addCallback(object : Callback() {
        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)
            // moving to a new thread
            ioThread {
                getInstance(context).dataDao()
                                    .insert(PREPOPULATE_DATA)
            }
        }
    })
    .build()
```

Comment: the problem i can't , i said that in question ,i have a lot of tables and rows so i can't do that manually